# Unable to install npm module on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install node modules on my raspberry pi 2, but it always through me an error 'EHOSTUNREACH 151.101.60.162:443'

For example, with a `npm install pi-gpio`, the complete error is:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.38+
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "pi-gpio"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! errno EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! connect EHOSTUNREACH 151.101.60.162:443
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/
```

I'm connected to my raspberry pi through ssh and i've put it a fixed ip address on it.

My node version

```
v4.0.0
```

My npm version

```
2.14.2
```

My raspberry info

```
$> uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.38+ #938 Thu Dec 15 15:17:54 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Does anyone knows what is going wrong ?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6820 you have some network issues.. havent tried in raspberry-pi though. do `ping` and `traceroute` to registry.npmjs.org work?

Comment: thx for the quick reply. no, ping and traceroute doesnt work.

Comment: i i already checked the github issues link, but i don't have any proxy or permissions issue

Comment: it is probably general connectivity problem.. are you able to ping any general site? google?

Comment: mmm good point, no i can not reach google. Is it related to the fact that i'm connected under ssh ? Or the static ip adress ?

Comment: I am not sure about that. You should test it..

Comment: it was indeed a problem with my static IP address, the gateways was not the good one. thanks for the help anyway