# NPM cannot install packages EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: ubuntu, npm, raspberry-pi

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ npm install -g yarn
npm ERR! code EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! errno EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.ord/yarn failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 104.16.22.35:80
```

I have gone through every other link about this error and I have 3 factors that are different to all of them and they are important because they were the solution to everyone else's problems. Links I have read and have not solved the issue:

- [How to fix npm installation issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911529/how-to-fix-npm-installation-issue)
- [Node API failing with Error : EHOSTUNREACH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745075/node-api-failing-with-error-ehostunreach)
- https://groups.google.com/g/node-red/c/RVcv2GgO_Fw?pli=1
- https://stackabuse.com/npm-error-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-when-installing-module/
- https://discourse.nodered.org/t/node-installing-issue/50540/3
- ["message failed to fetch from registry" while trying to install any module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/message-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-while-trying-to-install-any-module)
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16098
- https://discourse.nodered.org/t/error-while-installing-dashboard-on-raspberry-pi/19291
- https://groups.google.com/g/node-red/c/RVcv2GgO_Fw
- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-private/3.2.x?topic=tap-cloud-foundry-application-deployment-fails-due-ehostunreach-error
- https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=61930
- https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/linux+redis+connect+EHOSTUNREACH
- https://forum.ghost.org/t/second-site-on-raspberry-pi-econnrefused/1230
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6820
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5553
- [npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371380/npm-err-error-connect-econnrefused)
- [Unable to install npm module on raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457198/unable-to-install-npm-module-on-raspberry-pi)
- https://githubmemory.com/repo/nicoduj/homebridge-harmony/issues/290
- https://discourse.nodered.org/t/node-installing-issue/50540

Still I'm struggling.

- Internet is stable and works
- I can ping `registry.npmjs.org` and other sites
- registry.npmjs.org isn't pointing to a local address

I have tried clearing proxy settings, I don't have proxy settings to try but is the only thing that it could be but I don't understand what to put there if needed (but considering the guides on how to clear it, they aren't required). I have no idea what to try as all of the solutions to every other instance does not apply to me.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 for Raspberry Pi

Comment: My "solution" ended up with going with CentOS which has worked fine

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

My setup: `npm` and `pnpm` on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a laptop

Worked for weeks without issue. Then suddenly I couldn't install anything. Example error messages from `pnpm add -D vite`:

```
 ERR_PNPM_META_FETCH_FAIL  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vite: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/vite failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH <redacted ipv6 address>
```

and

```
 WARN  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents error (EHOSTUNREACH). Will retry in 1 minute. 1 retries left.
```

Was able to browse to https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents via web browser no problem. Had internet.

Also tried installing packages with `npm`. That didn't work either.

`npm` version 8.19.2

`pnpm` version 7.19.0

## Solution

**Connecting to a VPN fixed it.** Don't know why.

Speculation: Maybe it has something to do with ipv6. Events leading up to the error: **1)** Connected to a VPN for the first time (new computer). **2)** Disconnected from the VPN (still had internet). **3)** Error struck the first time I tried installing something from NPM after disconnecting from the VPN. **4)** Re-connected to VPN; error gone.